# How do I authorize an API using custom attributes from Cognito user pools in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, lambda-authorizer

I have an API in AWS API Gateway. In the method request, I am using my custom Cognito authorizer as "Authorization" in Settings for a GET method on this API.

So I already have a mechanism to get an access token via Cognito. What I want to do now is access my **custom attribute** in the Cognito user pool.  The custom attribute is called StudentCode. I want, say, only students with code "500" to be authorized to use the GET method of my API.

How do I go about doing this with Cognito? Do I need to write a lambda authorizer or can this be done code-less using Cognito/API Gateway/etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe Lambda will be the one

Comment: How do I access custom attribute once given the access token though?

Comment: You can use this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html